admin showing Array() after adding exit() code
One of our developer add this code :  exit() somewhere in function.php file . now when we login to wp-admin, we are seeing below message :
Array()
we  renamed theme : "Hello-elementor", than admin started working. but website is not loading properly.
Is there any way to find in which file exit() code is added, so that we can remove it

Download your theme using Plugin: Download Theme, and search using code editor like VSCode.
